# VBA conditional search and marking

Tags: search, conditional-statements, cell, background-color

The aim is to search in column A for the word "XXX". When the word is found in that column, the next cell should match the word "C".If it doesn't, carry on with the search for "XXX" in the next row, etc. The issue in my code is that it marks all "C"s. In other words, there is no conditional search where XXX=C.

[image]

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Select Case cell.Value2
        Case "XXX"
            col = RGB(202, 225, 255)
        Case Else
            col = 0
    End Select


    If col > 0 Then
        wb.Activate
        cell.Interior.Color = col
        For Each cell2 In cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(1).SpecialCells  (xlCellTypeConstants)
        res = Switch(cell2.Value = "C", vbGreen)
        If Not IsNull(res) Then Intersect(Range("B:B, J:J, L:L, N:N, Q:Q"), Rows(cell2.Row)).Interior.Color = CLng(res) '
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: See Below

Slightly unsure what you're asking but I think solution is below.
I have used much simpler code but it should be adequate.

```
For xJ = 1 to 200
    If Range("A" & xJ).Value = "XXX" then
        Range("A" & xJ).Interior.Color = RGB(202, 225, 255)
        If Range("B" & xJ).Value = "C" Then
            Range("B" & xJ).Interior.Color = RGB(57, 225, 20)
        End If
    End if
Next xJ
```

Comment: Thx. It almost fits the purpose.The aim is to mark all "XXX" in one collor and all "C"s in the next cell of "XXX" in green only when XXX and "C" are next to each other.